# Javascript worker receive message is never being called

Tags: javascript, cordova, worker, devextreme

```
function receiveMessage(e) {
    alert("received message");
    if (e.data.success === "log") {
        console.log(e.data.result);
       return;
   }
    if (e.data.finished) {
        workerCount--;
        if (workerCount) {
            if (resultArray.length == 0) {
                DecodeWorker.postMessage({ ImageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height).data, Width: Canvas.width, Height: Canvas.height, cmd: "flip", Decode: "Code39"});
            } else {
                workerCount--;
            }
        }
    }
    if (e.data.success) {
        var tempArray = e.data.result;
        for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            if (resultArray.indexOf(tempArray[i]) == -1) {
                resultArray.push(tempArray[i]);
            }
        }
        alert(resultArray[0]);
    } else {
        if (resultArray.length === 0 && workerCount === 0) {
            alert("Decoding failed.");
        }
    }
}

var DecodeWorker = new Worker("js/BarcodeScanner.js");
DecodeWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
// Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
    // console.log(imageData);
    smallPicture = document.getElementById('smallImage');
    // Get image handle
    //

    // Unhide image elements
    //
    smallPicture.style.display = 'block';

    // Show the captured photo
    // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
    //
    smallPicture.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(smallPicture, 0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);


        resultArray = [];

        workerCount = 2;
        alert("Prepost");
        barcodeNum("");
        alert("Post");
        DecodeWorker.postMessage({ ImageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height).data, Width: Canvas.width, Height: Canvas.height, cmd: "normal", Decode: "Code39" });
};


    smallPicture.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}
```

When using the postMessage function on my decodeWorker the receiveMessage function is never being called, and I can't figure out what exactly it is that I'm doing wrong, It seems that worst case scenario I would atleast see teh 'received message' alert that I set up, but even that doesn't occur.

Comment: Well, can´t say much without the js/BarcodeScanner.js file

Comment: Its an exact copy of this https://github.com/EddieLa/BarcodeReader/blob/master/src/DecoderWorker.js

Comment: And `smallPicture.onload` is running?

Comment: Yes, I think I found the problem.  I was running the app through courier provided by devexpress.  Which was making the worker take literally a minute per message.  I packaged it to my android and it worked as intended.

Comment: Great, good you got it working